# How to make partial changes in attribute table without missing with the whole data?

Tags: attributes, gis, arcgis, qgis, alphanumeric

I want to change some letters in attribute table of the image below, for example: change code from **"PK705"** to **"NA705"**. SO what I mean is changing the first two letters without missing with the code numbers of the the rest of attribute table.
Any suggested trick for the solution, it would be appreciated.

[Attribute table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nafBy.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have already got the list of the attributes value

```
adm2_pcode = ['PK631','PK632','PK816','PK614','PK219','PK620','PK705','PK613','PK611','PK601','PK235']
```

Use str.replace(old, new ) to change it:

```
adm2_pcode = [adm2_pcode[i].replace('PK','NA') for i in range(len(adm2_pcode))]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've found easier solution that doesn't require much coding knowledge which is a function called 'replace' that could be used for attribute table.